# Vim-Latex spell checking : ignore comment regions

Tags: tools, vim, spelling

I'm using the Vim-Latex environment for writing french documents. The problem is that when I comment a line containing a command, the spell checking tool highlights the command as a spelling mistake.

Is it possible to set the spell check tool in a way that it ignore commented lines?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

there is an option for that, you just have to add

```
let g:tex_comment_nospell=1
```

in your `.vimrc`.

About the internals, this variable is used in the file `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/tex.vim` in my installation.

[Edit for older versions]

Checking vim source tree in older versions, this variable appears [from revision 1073](http://vim.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vim/branches/vim7.2/runtime/syntax/tex.vim?annotate=1073), which is after vim 7.0 and 7.1. As stated by the diff, this modification introduces the lines

```
if !exists("g:tex_comment_nospell") || !g:tex_comment_nospell
    syn cluster texCommentGroup contains=texTodo,@Spell
else
    syn cluster texCommentGroup contains=texTodo,@NoSpell
endif
```

so maybe adding

```
:autocmd BufEnter *.tex syntax cluster texCommentGroup contains=texTodo,@NoSpell
```

in your `.vimrc` would do the trick, at least it works on vim 7.3. If this does not work, you could try to get a more recent syntax file and put it into `.vim/syntax/tex.vim`

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer. May it be related to the fact that i'm using Vim 7.0? I hope it's not because I can't upgrade to 7.3 (professional computer without root access...)

Comment: I checked the source tree, and indeed, the variable only appears in `tex.vim` from vim 7.2.

Comment: I used this line `let g:tex_comment_nospell=1` in the file `tex_latexsuite.vim` just below `set spell`, but it didn't work. If I set it in `.vimrc`, then it works. No idea why that happens.